# error after present controller

Tags: swift, swift3.2

I used from https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu programmatically on my Controller with swift 3.2

```
    let menuSlide =  DrawerViewController();

    SideMenuManager.menuWidth = 200
    SideMenuManager.menuRightNavigationController = menuSlide
    SideMenuManager.menuFadeStatusBar = false
    SideMenuManager.menuPresentMode = .menuSlideIn
    SideMenuManager.menuAnimationFadeStrength = 0.5
    SideMenuManager.menuAnimationTransformScaleFactor = 1


    SideMenuManager.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView:  self.view)
```

and worked! but first present controller

after present again with

```
   let main = mainController()
    self.present(main, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

from other controller The following error occurs

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

(lldb)

thanks for help me

Comment: Please use this https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController . its easy and manageable

Comment: You missed out the important part of the error output

Comment: Show the whole error message.There should be lines before "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException", and they are important. From pure guesses, I'd say that `mainController` is a `UIViewController` in a Storyboard/XIB.